# to map a range of numbers in an array to uniform random 1 to 100

Tags: java, c++, random, uniform

I have 5 dice and I roll each of them once: say outcome is dice[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }

this dice[] array is the input to a function say

```
 int  random (dice) {
   //do some thing with the dice values { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 } ( as input from user )

   //return a uniform random number between 1 to 100

 }
```

Rule: only source of randomness is the values in the dice array. How do I may each of the values to a number in 1 to 100 so that the resulting values are almost uniform generation

please help

Answer (score 1):

You could multiply the numbers on the dice by 1, 6, 6^2, 6^3, 6^4 respectively.  Then add them up and take the last two digits of the result (that is, do a % 100 at the end).

**Edit** (thanks pjs)

As a last step, add 1, so that you get an answer between 1 and 100, not between 0 and 99.

Comment: Don't forget to add one to shift the range from [0,99] to [1,100].  Some bins occur slightly more often than others, but that's unavoidable since 6**5 isn't evenly divisible by 100.

Comment: @pjs Oh, good point about the +1.  I knew that this wasn't perfectly uniform, but the question specified "almost uniform generation".

Comment: Yeah, I noted the "almost" as well.  I still checked it explicitly, and the bin counts are all either 77 or 78, i.e., they only differ by 1.  I can't see how you could do better than that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to generate random numbers anywhere from 1 to 100. You can check out how the C++ rand() function works [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/), or the Java Math.random() function [here](http://java.about.com/od/javautil/a/randomnumbers.htm).

Comment: No.  The question says the "only source of randomness is the values in the dice array".